# Boost spirit qi - parse string into boolean

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit-qi

I need to parse a string into a boolean value; in particular

- if the string is `ack` I want the parser sets a boolean variable with `true`;
- if the string is `noack` I want the parser sets a boolean variable with `false`;

Note that I do not want to use the return value of the function `qi::parse`; I want the `qi::parse` function sets a boolean variable given as argument. Something like the following (not compiling) code:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::spirit;

int main() {
    bool b;
    std::string s("ack");
    auto it = s.begin();
    if (qi::parse(it, s.end(), < need a rule here... >, b))
        std::cout << "Value: " << std::boolalpha << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach that comes to mind is `"noack" >> qi::attr(false)` and its complement. Add an `eoi` to ensure full input is parsed:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce1ec5f9ac1879e3)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    for (std::string const s : {"ack","noack","oops","ack 2",""}) {
        bool b;
        if (qi::parse(s.begin(), s.end(), ("ack" >> qi::attr(true) | "noack" >> qi::attr(false)) >> qi::eoi, b))
            std::cout << "'" << s << "' -> " << std::boolalpha << b << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "'" << s << "' -> FAIL\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
'ack' -> true
'noack' -> false
'oops' -> FAIL
'ack 2' -> FAIL
'' -> FAIL
```

### BONUS:

Use `symbol` for more elegance:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab424753d88cb4c0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct acknoack_type : qi::symbols<char, bool> {
    acknoack_type() { this->add("ack", true)("noack", false); }
} static const acknoack;

int main() {
    for (std::string const s : {"ack","noack","oops","ack 2",""}) {
        bool b;
        if (qi::parse(s.begin(), s.end(), acknoack >> qi::eoi, b))
            std::cout << "'" << s << "' -> " << std::boolalpha << b << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "'" << s << "' -> FAIL\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i do not want that the parser fails on "noack"; in this case I want it sets the boolean with `false`.

Comment: Whoops. As you can clearly see from how I explained the parser expression that was exactly how I intended it. By the way, the second already works, so you can always use that. I'll look at the first later

Comment: Fixed. My understanding of `qi::matches` was wrong. Thanks for teaching me again :)